# How to make a custom hook respond to changes in state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a custom hook that processes a certain state variable.

Whenever you change the state It does not update immediately so I have to subscribe to it using useEffect.

However it is categorically impossible to call a custom hook within useEffect.

How does one get their custom hooks to do anything at all with a state variable?

Comment: Please visit help center, take [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search) for related topics on Stackoverflow; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Why can't you call your custom hook in an `useEffect` hook? Hooks can be called from the body of functional components and other hooks. What have you tried? Please share a minimal, complete, and reproducible code example.

Comment: @DrewReese this appears to be a follow up from a previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66020140/work-around-to-use-custom-hook-in-useeffect

Comment: So, seems this question should be closed/deleted then and conversation moved back to the original question?

Comment: This question is a more general design pattern about react. My previous question is a particular example looking for a work-around. And no, you can't run a custom hook inside useEffect, because that in itself is a hook.

Comment: I think you're right. Just tested this and the custom hook is flagged by the linter, but it actually compiles and runs the custom hook in the `useEffect` callback (actually throws error if custom hook calls other hooks). It's subtle, but yeah, the effect callback *isn't* actually in the `useEffect` hook itself, so I agree with you. Well, either way, I left a comment in your other question where you can pass dependencies to custom hooks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not (*should* not) call a custom hook inside of `useEffect`, but you can use `useEffect` inside of your custom hook:

```
const useMyHook = function( someState ){
    useEffect( function(){
        // do what the hook should do
    }, [ someState ]);
};
```

If the hook should update also when something else changes, you can just pass that as well:

```
const useMyHook = function( someState, someDependency ){
    useEffect( function(){
        // do what the hook should do
    }, [ someState, someDependency ]);
};
```

I suggest to use an array for the dependencies, so that it works similar to `useEffect`:

```
const useMyHook = function( label, dependencies ){

    const [ value, setValue ] = useState(0);

    useEffect( function(){
        setValue( value + 1 );
    }, [ label, ...dependencies ]);

    return label + ': ' + value;
};

// ...

const value = useMyHook('counter', [ dependentValue, otherDependentValue ]);
```